# How to give permission for the cron job file?

Tags: cron

I have set the cron tab for my site. But I have got message in my mailing id like this "Permission denied" for the script. Can anyone help me telling what may be the problem.

Thanks......

Answer (score 10):

You get this error while setting the crontab? or from a script running from the cron?

If while setting the crontab, try this:

> You type: crontab -e
>   You get:  -bash: /usr/bin/crontab: Permission denied
>
> Problem:  Your user is not in the cron group.
>
> Solution: As root, edit the /etc/group file, find the cron group and add
>           your user to that line (the usernames are comma-separated).
>           Then re-login as your user.
>
> Verify:       Run command "groups". You should see "cron" in there.

(from http://www.parseerror.com/argh/crontab-e-Permission-denied.txt)

Comment: If `cron` isn't listed in `/etc/groups` (but `crontab:x:107:` is), is it safe to add it? Context: Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 4):

friends if any one wants schedule crons from other user
just do this

root user:-

```
ls /usr/bin/crontab
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/crontab

echo PATH
vi /etc/crontab

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

cd /etc/cron.d
```

create cron.allow file if not exist

```
vi cron.allow
root
other username
```

save and exist

```
su – username
/usr/bin/crontab -e
```

schedule here ……………….

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today and was baffled until I realized that the denied commands were SSH commands. I had forgotten that I was connecting with an SSH key that required a passphrase, so the real issue had nothing to do with cron in my case.

My solution was to create an additional key for this script with no passphrase (using `ssh-keygen`), install it on the remote server, and specify it in the script with the -i flag to the ssh commands.

```
ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa.no-passphrase user@remote command-to-run
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sudo -i
$adduser your-user crontab
```