# C script running as cron giving permission denied error

Tags: c, cron

I have a .c file compiled and would like to run via a cron job but I end up getting this error:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/get1Receive.c: Permission denied.
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Should I be running the `.c` file in cron or a different compiled file?

Results from /tmp/myvars

```
GROUPS=()
HOME=/root
HOSTNAME=capture
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
IFS='
'
LOGNAME=root
MACHTYPE=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
OPTERR=1
OPTIND=1
OSTYPE=linux-gnu
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
POSIXLY_CORRECT=y
PPID=11086
PS4='+ '
PWD=/root
SHELL=/bin/sh
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix
SHLVL=1
TERM=dumb
UID=0
USER=root
_=/bin/sh
```

Results from file get1Receive.c

```
file get1Receive.c
get1Receive.c: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

Snippet of codes.

```
sprintf(queryBuf1,"SELECT ipDest, macDest,portDest, sum(totalBits) FROM dataReceive WHERE timeStampID between '%s' And '%s'  GROUP BY ipDest, macDest, portDest ",buff1,buff2);
                printf("\nQuery receive %s",queryBuf1);


                if(mysql_query(localConn, queryBuf1))
                {
                    //fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(localConn));
                    printf("Error in first query of select %s\n",mysql_error(localConn));
                    exit(1);
                }

                localRes1 = mysql_store_result(localConn);
                int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(localRes1);

                printf("\nNumf of fields : %d",num_fields);
                printf("\nNof of row : %lu",mysql_num_rows(localRes1));
```

Comment: Did you actually specify the `.c` file as to be executed? Replace it with the binary file resulting from the `gcc` run.

Comment: @glglgl I have tried ./get1Receive.c it runs smoothly.

Comment: @biz14: is this a C program, or a c-shell script?  Does the line start `#!`, if so, what follows?  You cannot run a C program without compiling it or running it in somesort of framework.

Comment: @cdarke the get1Receive1.c is the compile output from the gcc - o.

Comment: @biz14 - really? That is unusual, usually that is the name of the source code (sure it isn't a.out?).  Anyway, `chmod u+x filename` should give you what you need.

Comment: @cdarke I have chmod +x it works but not the query to my db?

Comment: @biz14: Sorry, but without seeing the source code it would be useless for me to guess what "my db" is, how you are accessing it, or what is wrong.  Show your code, and show the errors you are getting.

Comment: This is almost certainly an environment issue.  When you run a cron job your startup files are not run.  If your database access is dependant on something setup in .profile or .bash_profile then it won't be run.  You need to "source" your startup files in a script, which then runs your program.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26043/discussion-between-biz14-and-cdarke)

Comment: @cdarke I have updated my question with snippet of my codes. I am not sure what my database is dependent on it is mysql db.

Comment: @biz14: I can't tell what is wrong from that.  What happens when you run the job, do you get an error message.  If not, why not?  Are you checking every API call?  Take a step back.  Write a simple program that just writes to stdout (why are you error messages going to stdout instead of stderr?).  Do you get the message?  Now add a database connection, and so on, one step at a time.

Comment: @cdarke yes I am quite new to all this. So how should I put my stderr?

Comment: Seems to me that you should ask a new question tagged `mysql`.  Show all your code, including the connect.  However, did you try sourcing your start-up files as I suggested?

Comment: @cdarke yes I think I will do that ask a new question tagged both with mysql and c. I dont get you regarding the sourcing of start-up files? What start-up files are you mentioning here?Sorry I am kind of new into this?

Comment: Startup files .profile or .bash_profile, either could be in your home directory.  ls -al to see them (filenames starting with a . are normally "hidden").

Comment: I am not too sure since I am running as root's .bash_profile shows me this

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

Answer (score 3):

If the output of this command:

```
file  get1Receive1.c
```

shows that file name to be a valid executable that part is very unusual, but okay.

Assuming you are using biz14  (or your real username's ) crontab try this:

use the command `crontab -e`  to create this line in your crontab:

```
* * * * *  set > /tmp/myvars
```

Wait a few minutes, go back into `crontab -e` and delete that entry.

Use the set command from the command line to see what variables and aliases exist.
Compare that with that you see in `/tmp/myvars`  You have to change how your C code executes by changing the variables and aliases the cron job runs with.

If you are running the cron job in someone else's crontab, then you have a bigger problem. Check file permissions on  get1Receive1.c.  and the directory it lives in.  That other user (the one who wons the crontab) has to have permissions set on your directory and  get1Receive1.c so the job can run.

Example crontab entry:

```
0 10 * * 1-5 /path/to/get1Receive1.c > /tmp/outputfile
```

Read `/tmp/outputfile` to see what you got.   You are using `printf` in your code.  `printf` only writes to the controlling terminal.  There is no controlling terminal, so redirect the `printf` stuff to a file.

Last effort on this problem:
Check return codes on EVERYTHING. All C functions like fread(), any db function, etc. If a return code gives a fail response ( these are different for different function calls) then report the error number the line number and function - gcc provides **LINE** and **func**. Example:

```
printf("error on line %d in my code %s, error message =%s\n", __LINE__, __func__, [string of error message]);
```

If you do not check return codes you are writing very poor C code.

CHECK return codes, please, now!

Comment: I have update my question with both the results I am not too sure what to change now in my C codes? Any suggestion? I am running the cron as root.

Comment: chmod 755 get1Receive1.c  ( or whatever the new name is).  Since you are running as root (which can be dangerous) supply the full path, example: /home/biz14/get1Receive1.c   in your crontab entry. --  Use the new name for your file since you've changed it.

Comment: why is it dangerous to run as root? So how to change to other users? I just chmod 755 and it is still not generating the query results even with chmod 755?

Comment: You seem new to all this.  That means you may do something really bad, unintentionally.  Like delete or mv an important file so the system cannot boot properly.  Having full privilege and being new is a dangerous combination. Add another user to the system, let that unprivileged, regular user run the job.  Change permissions on directories and the executable file so the new user can run the job. I have no clue as to why you got no output, but it is probably related to one of the settings.  try this as part of the crontab:    /path/to/getReceive > /tmp/outputfile <-- Look at that file at end.

Comment: I edited the answer above to show you how to run the job. The "time part" was just an example (time part = first five columns like * * * * *)  
It will run M-F at 10:00am.

Comment: I have checked the file and it prints everything except that the  printf("\nNof of row : %lu",mysql_num_rows(localRes1)); always give me 0 meaning that there is no results but in real fact when I copy back into mysql and run the same query there is results?

Comment: I do not know why.  Are you checking return codes on ALL calls to the db?

Comment: the reason why I am doing that is was to know at which point does my cronjob is stop functioning?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: where exactly to put this return codes is it after call of the query in my case? For e.g. in my case in this  if(mysql_query(localConn, queryBuf1)) statement?

Comment: I put the suggested line and got error get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: expected expression before â[â token
get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: âstringâ undeclared (first use in this function)
get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: for each function it appears in.)
get1ReceiveSource.c:56: error: expected expression before â[â token

Comment: This: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: for each function it appears in) is a GCC compiler error complaining about your code.  This means your "executable" is not an executable.  It needs to be compiled.

Comment: this is how I compiled and got the errors gcc -o get1Receive $(mysql_config --cflags) get1ReceiveSource.c $(mysql_config --libs) -lrt
get1ReceiveSource.c: In function âmainâ:
get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: expected expression before â[â token
get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: âstringâ undeclared (first use in this function)
get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
get1ReceiveSource.c:52: error: for each function it appears in.)
get1ReceiveSource.c:56: error: expected expression before â[â token

Answer (score 1):

Permission wise you could have two issues.
1. The 'c' file's permissions don't allow who you are running it as to run it.
2. You are running the cron with a script which doesn't have permissions.

Here's a helpful post: [How to give permission for the cron job file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892104/how-to-give-permission-for-the-cron-job-file)

The fact that you are running a 'c' file and referring to it as a script makes me think you're using C shell and not writing it as a C language program which would need to be compiled and have the generated executable run by the cron. If you're not using gcc or have never called gcc on your 'C' script then it's not C and call it C shell to avoid confusion.

Comment: usually when folks identify scripts with the name,  the local standards usually involve [scriptname].[suffix]  where suffix identifies  the type of script: .csh, .ksh, or maybe .sh.  Using .c would be really confusing.  I'm wondering if the  get1Receive1.c file (the source) was overwritten somehow during the compile. And the source has gone bye-bye.

Comment: @jimmcnamara get1Receive1.c is the output from gcc -o so what should I  give the suffix for .c output files?

Comment: @biz14: usually UNIX/Linux compiled binary files do not have a filename suffix.  For example, you call `ls`, not ls.exe.

Comment: @cdarke ok I wont compile it with .c any more but my problem now the crontab can run my script but cant give me the query results I have updated my question with two more results suggested by jim can you suggest what I must do now?